# Go project's main goroutine sleep forever?

Tags: go, blocking, goroutine

Is there any API to let the `main` goroutine sleep forever?

In other words, I want my project always run except when I stop it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

#### "Sleeping"

You can use numerous constructs that block forever without "eating" up your CPU.

For example a `select` without any `case` (and no `default`):

```
select{}
```

Or receiving from a channel where nobody sends anything:

```
<-make(chan int)
```

Or receiving from a `nil` channel also blocks forever:

```
<-(chan int)(nil)
```

Or sending on a `nil` channel also blocks forever:

```
(chan int)(nil) <- 0
```

Or locking an already locked `sync.Mutex`:

```
mu := sync.Mutex{}
mu.Lock()
mu.Lock()
```

#### Quitting

If you do want to provide a way to quit, a simple channel can do it. Provide a `quit` channel, and receive from it. When you want to quit, close the `quit` channel as "a receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received".

```
var quit = make(chan struct{})

func main() {
    // Startup code...

    // Then blocking (waiting for quit signal):
    <-quit
}

// And in another goroutine if you want to quit:
close(quit)
```

Note that issuing a `close(quit)` may terminate your app at any time. Quoting from [Spec: Program execution:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. **It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.**

When `close(quit)` is executed, the last statement of our `main()` function can proceed which means the `main` goroutine can return, so the program exits.

### Sleeping without blocking

The above constructs block the goroutine, so if you don't have other goroutines running, that will cause a deadlock.

If you don't want to block the `main` goroutine but you just don't want it to end, you may use a [`time.Sleep()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) with a sufficiently large duration. The max duration value is

```
const maxDuration time.Duration = 1<<63 - 1
```

which is approximately 292 years.

```
time.Sleep(time.Duration(1<<63 - 1))
```

If you fear your app will run longer than 292 years, put the above sleep in an endless loop:

```
for {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1<<63 - 1))
}
```

Comment: Not working. The program crashes with `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: @recolic The answer shows how to block the main goroutine. If all your other goroutines block as well, that's obviously a deadlock. If you get that, you're doing something wrong in your other goroutines, or you shouldn't block unconditionally your main.

Comment: I'm simply writing a program to trick windows defender. In other word, I'm implementing a deadlock. ( https://git.recolic.net/bensl/file-share/blob/master/fuck-windows-defender/main.go )

Comment: @recolic I don't see your code, I obviously can't reason about it. If you have a specific question, post a new question.

Comment: @recolic You have a single (main) gorotuine and you block that. What else would you expect?

Comment: I'm working on replacing the WindowsDefender executable with this dead program, so WindowsDefender stop performing heavy IO operation while I'm gaming...

Comment: @recolic If you just want to wait indefinitely, use a big duration with sleep, e.g. `time.Sleep(time.Duration(1<<63 - 1))`

Answer (score 8):

It depends on use cases to choose what kind of sleep you want.

@icza provides a good and simple solution for literally sleeping forever, but I want to give you some more sweets if you want your system could shutdown gracefully.

You could do something like this:

```
func mainloop() {
    exitSignal := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(exitSignal, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-exitSignal

    systemTeardown()
}
```

And in your main:

```
func main() {
    systemStart()
    mainloop()
}
```

In this way, you could not only ask your main to sleep forever, but you could do some graceful shutdown stuff after your code receives `INT` or `TERM` signal from OS, like `ctrl+C` or `kill`.

Comment: I think you should use a buffered channel `exitSignal := make(chan os.Signal, 1)`, otherwise it shows this error https://github.com/hlandau/service/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to block a goroutine. This solution prevents Go-Runtime to complain about the deadlock:

```golang
import "time"

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1138800 * time.Hour)
    }
}
```