# What does select{} do?

Tags: select, go, concurrency

Reading [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7), I fell on this code snippet.

```
var limit = make(chan int, 3)

func main() {
    for _, w := range work {
        go func(w func()) {
            limit <- 1
            w()
            <-limit
        }(w)
    }
    select{}
}
```

I understand what this function is supposed to do – limit concurrency to 3 goroutines at any time – but I don't understand what the final `select{}` does. I expect this is some way to keep `main` alive until all goroutines have finished running, but I can't really say for sure.

What happens in an empty `select`?

Comment: Check out this question: [Go project's main goroutine sleep forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419054/go-projects-main-goroutine-sleep-forever/36419222#36419222)

Answer (score 2):

In generally, `select{}` is used for infinite loop.