# Golang: forever channel

Tags: go, channel

Just have a question, what is happening here?

```
forever := make(chan bool)

log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
<-forever
```

Comment: open a delve session and disassemble, or just `[s,d]trace` the process. You'll see that what icza sais in his answer is exactly what is going on: `<-forever` is a blocking operation. Similarly `forever<-true` would block, too (because no routine is reading from the channel)

Comment: Channels are covered thoroughly in the excellent [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That code creates an unbuffered channel, and attempts to receive from it.

And since no one ever sends anything on it, it's essentially a blocking forever operation.

The *purpose* of this is to keep the goroutine from ending / returning, most likely because there are other goroutines which do some work concurrently or they wait for certain events or incoming messages (like your log message says).

And the *need* for this is that without this, the application might quit without waiting for other goroutines. Namely, if the `main` goroutine ends, the program ends as well. Quoting from [Spec: Program execution:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.

Check out this answer for similar and more techniques: [Go project's main goroutine sleep forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419054/go-projects-main-goroutine-sleep-forever/36419222#36419222)

For an introduction about channels, see [What are channels used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826692/what-are-golang-channels-used-for/39826883#39826883)