# Are all runtime errors recoverable in Go?

Tags: go

I think an equivalent question is - do all runtime errors, which may be fatal, panic? Because anything that panics should be recoverable. I'm not talking about recovering from things like `os.Exit()`, or `log.Fatal()`, or bugs in the Go runtime, or someone tripping over the power cord, but from other runtime errors which will lead to the program crashing.

Here's an example of a runtime error that can be caught via panic/recover:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func errorHandler() {
    r := recover()
    err := r.(error)
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()
    smallSlice := []int{1, 0, 1}
    smallSlice[10] = 1
}

func main() {
    foo()
    fmt.Println("recovery, end of main")
}
```

output:

> runtime error: index out of range
>   recovery, end of main

Are there any examples where runtime errors will just crash the program without a recoverable panic?

Comment: Take a look at all the `throw()` calls in the runtime if you want to see most of the fatal runtime errors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First change your `errorHandler()` because if there are no panics, `r` will be `nil` and thus the type assertion would fail:

```
func errorHandler() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

And now here are some examples with code to produce unrecoverable runtime errors:

#### 1. Out of memory:

```
func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()
    _ = make([]int64, 1<<40) // You have to change the size on 32-bit systems
}
```

#### 2. Concurrent map writes and reads

For details see [How to recover from concurrent map writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288741/how-to-recover-from-concurrent-map-writes/39289246#39289246), for example see [Can marshalling a map[string]string to json return an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239367/can-marshalling-a-mapstringstring-to-json-return-an-error/49240146#49240146)

```
func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()
    m := map[string]int{}

    go func() {
        for {
            m["x"] = 1
        }
    }()
    for {
        _ = m["x"]
    }
}
```

#### 3. Stack memory exhaustion

For details, see [Does Go have an "infinite call stack" equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940414/does-go-have-an-infinite-call-stack-equivalent/49940717#49940717)

```
func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()

    var f func(a [1000]int64)
    f = func(a [1000]int64) {
        f(a)
    }
    f([1000]int64{})
}
```

#### 4. Attempting to launch a `nil` function as a goroutine

```
func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()
    var f func()
    go f()
}
```

#### 5. All goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Title says it all. Here's a simple code to block the current goroutine, but if you have launched other goroutines, you obviously won't experience the crash. See other examples here: [Go project's main goroutine sleep forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419054/go-projects-main-goroutine-sleep-forever/36419222#36419222)

```
func foo() {
    defer errorHandler()
    select {}
}
```

#### 6. Thread limit exhaustion

If your goroutines get blocked by IO operations, new threads may be started to execute your other goroutines. There is obviously a limit to the max thread count, if it is reached, your app will crash.

Comment: We could on an on here, there's a lot of `throw()`s in the runtime package, and a data race could really get you anything. Regular SIGSEGVs (without `debug.SetPanicOnFault`), `sync: unlock of unlocked mutex`, `inconsistent mutex state` , `alloc too large`, all `throw()` off the top of my head.

Answer (score 9):

> Are there any examples where runtime errors will just crash the
>   program without a recoverable panic?

---

For example, Go Out-Of-Memory (OOM) errors are not recoverable.

---

> `src/runtime/panic.go`:
>
> ```
> // fatalpanic implements an unrecoverable panic. It is like fatalthrow, except
> // that if msgs != nil, fatalpanic also prints panic messages and decrements
> // runningPanicDefers once main is blocked from exiting.
> func fatalpanic(msgs *_panic) {
>     // ...
> }
>
> // fatalthrow implements an unrecoverable runtime throw. It freezes the
> // system, prints stack traces starting from its caller, and terminates the
> // process.
> func fatalthrow() {
>     // ...
> }
> ```